# Connect Raspberry Pi to iPhone without existing Wi-Fi network

Tags: ios, bluetooth, wifi, raspberry-pi, wifi-direct

I’m building a gizmo* with a Raspberry Pi, and I would like to connect it to an iPhone app to control it and, if possible, stream images or even live video to the iPhone. I would like to avoid the headache of either having both devices on the same Wi-Fi network, or having one create an ad-hoc network that the other joins. Therefore, I would prefer Bluetooth or Wi-Fi Direct.

Since this is a hobbyist project, and I don’t intend to sell it, joining the Made for iPhone program isn’t an option. Is there a way that I can connect an iPhone to a Raspberry Pi over Wi-Fi Direct or Bluetooth/BTLE, without using private methods, that does not require neither the MFi program nor having both devices join the same network?

<sub>*I’m building a juggling club with a camera inside, to record video like [this](http://youtu.be/AHp4uflcDEI).</sub>

Comment: BLE is outside of MFi but it won't have the bandwidth to support video streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware the latest version of iOS (at time of writing) does not support Wi-Fi Direct, so this would not be an option.  Equally the public Multipeer connectivity API and private BluetoothManager are also not suitable, the former is for iOS devices only.  If the Bluetooth dongle in the RaspPi is Bluetooth Low-Energy, then the Core Bluetooth API should allow for iPhone to Pi communication.

Comment: Aw drat, didn’t realize Multipeer Connectivity was limited to iOS only. I guess I’ll give BTLE a try, then.